# set System.getenv in Linux

Tags: java, getenv

Im building some application, where i would like to get some variable directly from linux.

I know, that the command to get the variable is System.getenv(), but i don't exackly know where i should set variable in linux.

I'm using Centos, and my tomcat is set in /usr/share/tomcat6

I was thinking, that maybe i should write it in /etc/profile file, but it doesn't works, and additionally i think that i should past the variable in user folder. User for Tomcat is tomcat, and his folder is /usr/share/tomcat6.

Should i create there file `profile` and add something like this? :

```
MY_VARIABLE=value
export MY_VARIABLE
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

From Terminal:

```
  gedit ~/.bashrc
```

~ here refers to /home/USER directory.

Edit the file:

```
  MY_VARIABLE=value 
  export MY_VARIABLE
```

confirm changes:

```
  echo $MY_VARIABLE
```

Comment: .bashrc is just for bash not jvm!